# How to use function (writePower:completion:) using Estimote SDK?

Tags: objective-c, object

I'm quite new to object-c so it seems that even if I saw the SDK, I can't use it well..sigh.
My problem is I don't know to use this function in code:

```
- (void)writePower:(ESTBeaconPower)power completion:(ESTPowerCompletionBlock)completion
```

And more definitions:

```
typedef void(^ESTPowerCompletionBlock)(ESTBeaconPower value, NSError* error);
typedef enum : char
{
    ESTBeaconPowerLevel8 = 4
} ESTBeaconPower;
```

My wrong code is like:

```
[self writePower:(ESTBeaconPower)ESTBeaconPowerLevel8 completion:(ESTPowerCompletionBlock)(ESTBeaconPower ESTBeaconPowerLevel8, NSError* error)]
```

Error is Expected ')' ...

Can someone helps me thanks.. I feel I don't understand 'completion' well.

Answer (score 0):

The `completion` argument is supposed to be a block that is apparently called when whatever this method does completes. If you haven't learned this sort of thing, I would suggest [learning Objective-C](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH1-SW1). [Here's the blocks section](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithBlocks/WorkingwithBlocks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH8-SW1), but it would all be useful if you don't know it.